# Form Action string changes when I publish my website and Upload it

Tags: asp.net, forms, http-post, webmethod

I have a ASP.Net From with action and method. It works fine in my local. But when I publish the website, the action is being changed to my page URL!!!

My page url is like :

```
http://localhost:37251/customeforms/cntrpage.aspx?protocol=7&msgtype=authorize
```

The Html that generates when I run my website on local is as follow: (InspectElement)

```
<form id="Form1" action="https://somepage/form/" method="post">
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value=".............." type="hidden">
<input id="t1" type="hidden" value="132" name="t1"></input>
<input id="t2" type="hidden" value="132" name="t2"></input>
<input id="t3" type="hidden" value="132" name="t3"></input>
<input id="t4" type="hidden" value="132" name="t4"></input>
</form>
```

But when I put it on public website, it turns into:

```
<form id="Form1" action="/customeforms/cntrpage.aspx?protocol=7&msgtype=authorize" method="post">

<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="............." type="hidden">
<input id="t1" type="hidden" value="132" name="t1"></input>
<input id="t2" type="hidden" value="132" name="t2"></input>
<input id="t3" type="hidden" value="132" name="t3"></input>
<input id="t4" type="hidden" value="132" name="t4"></input>
</form>
```

Anyone knows what's going on here???

-- EDIT --

I noticed that if the action url is empty it will be filled with current node URL. If that's my case, why is it being empty? 
Is it relevance?

Comment: How are you generating the URL? Show the code, not just the generated markup.

Comment: @Brandon, backend is simple, getting some values from querystring and processing them and fill form values. 
The question is why its acting different with same page and backend?

Comment: The current page's URL is not being generated. The main Action url is pointing to some payment gateways. But when I upload it to live server, the action url is being replaced by my current page's url